# How to use LIKE in dynamic SQL in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I wrote a stored procedure using dynamic SQL:

```
create procedure [dbo].[SearchProduct]
    (@ProductId int = null, @ProductName nvarchar(50) = null)
as
    declare @SqlStr nvarchar(max)
    declare @ParaList nvarchar(2000)

    set @SqlStr = 'select p.* from dbo.Product where (1=1) '

    if @ProductName is not null
       set @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'and(p.ProductName like '''%' + @ProductName2+'%''')'

    set @ParaList='@ProductId2 int , @ProductName2 nvarchar(50)'

    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SqlStr,@ParaList,@ProductId,@ProductName
```

But I get an error:

> Error in "Like operator" : The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.

If I change :

```
set @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 'and(p.ProductName like ''%' + @ProductName2+'%'')'
```

I get:

> @ProductName2 not declare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you look new to this please accept these notes from me:

1. As for your question... Your select statement ends with `where`  and you follow it with `and`

`select p.* from dbo.Product where '`

Also before `%` you should have only 2 single quotes not 3.. `Like ' '%' +....  + '%' '...`

2. When you do dynamic sql procedures,,,  always use `print()` method first instead of exec  to evaluate your sql.
3. Use  `case when` statement instead of `if statements.` it will organize your Code much better.
4. Since dynamic sql is really very bad practice ... Your question should be "how to convert this procedure to normal sql instead of dynamic..."

At the end, please accept my apologies for the lack of samples,  mistakes and help links as am answering  from my mobile phone.

Comment: Thank for your advice, @Sufyan. 1> I fixed. If i have 2 single quotes : error(Must declare @ProductName2). 2> and 3> I do it follow you. 4> Dynamic Sql is bad, but i want to search multi values and optimization algorithm : using dynamic sql.

Comment: @Mr.Ken at the worst, encapsulate the query through sp_executesql. You hide the entire statement and can dictate definitively how the variables are read and cleansed.

Comment: I use dynamic sql because i need search multi values in database. Do you have another optimal algorithms to solve this problem ? @clifton_h

Comment: @Mr.Ken I may have been a bit rash with my words, by all means use dynamic sql. Just use sp_executesql or sp_execute. `sp_executesql can be used instead of stored procedures to execute a Transact-SQL statement many times when the change in parameter values to the statement is the only variation. Because the Transact-SQL statement itself remains constant and only the parameter values change, the SQL Server query optimizer is likely to reuse the execution plan it generates for the first execution.` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) SQL Injection is prevented this way

Comment: So should i use Dynamic Sql ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a quote or two too many:

```
if @ProductName is not null
    set @SqlSt r = @SqlStr + 'and (p.ProductName like ''%' + @ProductName2+'%'')';
```

Within a string, two single quotes represent one single quote in the string.  The third single quote then ends the string.

Comment: But i get error : Must declare the scalar variable "@ProductName2".

Comment: @Mr.Ken . . . That variable is used in your original question.  I don't know how it gets assigned.

Answer (score 0):

should be below. You have the single quote wrongly

```
if @ProductName is not null
     set @SqlStr=@SqlStr+'and(p.ProductName like ''% + @ProductName2 + %'')'
```